I need to add a privacy policy to my flutter web app for Google verification
I have created a Flutter app and I am trying to integrate the Google Calendar API. As part of the process, I need to add a privacy policy link to the web version.
I have added the privacy policy to my website in the root directory and I can view the privacy policy by adding  button via LinkTile in the side menu. However, this is not a link because when I try to view the html page it does nothing.
How do I get this to display as an html file in a browser window?
How do I get this to register with Google?
Here is the code I am using:
 ListTile(
                leading: const Icon(
                  Icons.private_connectivity,
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
                title: const Text('Privacy Policy'),
                onTap: () {
                  if (kIsWeb) {
                    const PropertyWebViewScreenContainer('https://dealdiligencecentral.com/privacy_policy.html'); <<< This line does not work
                  } else {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                    Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => const PrivacyPolicyScreen()));
                  }
                  ;
                },
              ),

If the user is on a mobile device it will display on a new screen. If the user is on the web I want it to display in a new browser window.
How do I do this so Google will recognize it as a link?
Thanks

You can try out the [url_launcher][1] package, which allows you to open URLs in a browser.
Check out the below example.
ListTile(
  leading: const Icon(
    Icons.private_connectivity,
    color: Colors.blueAccent,
  ),
  title: const Text('Privacy Policy'),
  onTap: () {
    if (kIsWeb) {
      // This will open the privacy policy URL in a new browser window/tab on the web
      _launchURL('https://dealdiligencecentral.com/privacy_policy.html');
    } else {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const PrivacyPolicyScreen()));
    }
  },
)
void _launchURL(String url) async {
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url, webOnlyWindowName: '_blank'); // '_blank' opens in a new window
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}


you can simply use this code inside your onTap
import 'dart:js' as js;

if (kIsWeb) {
      // On web, open in a new browser tab
      js.context
          .callMethod('open', ['https://dealdiligencecentral.com/privacy_policy.html']);
    } else {
    //on mobile 
      Navigator.pop(context);
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const PrivacyPolicyScreen()));
    }

